# bat script for updating property file value

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am looking a batch script help to update a property file after every build through Jenkins. I want to update this file with Build version. Like

```
VER=1.234.44.5,1.234.44.6,1.234.44.7
```

And want to keep only `5` entries in there, so the new build removes the <strike>last</strike> first entry and adds the new version <strike>in first</strike> at the end.
Is it possible to do through batch script?

Comment: Whats you requirement? How does your input line looks like? And what is the expected output line?

Comment: I just want to update this file with the new enteries. Like new build should remove the last version entery 1.234.44.7 and add new version 1.234.44.8 in begining

VER=1.234.44.8, 1.234.44.5,1.234.44.6

Comment: In other Jenkins job it reads this property file and pre-populate parameterized build. So I can only select the version I need to do the build

Comment: Shouldn't your example be reversed? like `VER=1.234.7,1.234.6,1.234.5`

Comment: Thanks, you are right it should be look like more simple
VER=1.2.3.1, 1.2.3.2,1.2.3.3,1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5
Remove the 1.2.3.1 and add at the end 1.2.3.6

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I don't really understand your request. However, the Batch file below "Remove the 1.2.3.1 and add at the end 1.2.3.6" from `VER=1.2.3.1,1.2.3.2,1.2.3.3,1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set VER=1.2.3.1,1.2.3.2,1.2.3.3,1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5
echo Before: %VER%

for /F "tokens=2-5 delims=," %%a in ("%VER%") do (
   set next=%%~Xd
   set /A next=!next:~1!+1
   set VER=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%~Nd.!next!
)

echo After:  %VER%
```

Comment: Thanks Aacini, VER variable is in the build.properties file. Can you add steps that updates the properties file? 

I want to run this script at the end of Jenkins build job. This will update the build.properties with new version number. In second Jenkins job which does the deployment, read this build.properties file and populate available build versions to choose for deployment

Comment: And new version will  pass as a argument to this script. In your script it is calculating

Comment: Aacini, your script help to figure it me out how I can update. Here is the script that I made from yours.

**`@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set NV=%1
set PROP=%2
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (%PROP%) DO (
    IF "%%A"=="VER" set VERS=%%B
    )
echo Before: %VERS%
For /F "tokens=2-5 delims=," %%a in ("%VERS%") do (
  echo After: %%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%NV%
  echo VER=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%NV%>%PROP%
)
exit /b`**